# How to Send message to another scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two scenes in my game(Main Menu and Game).
There are two buttons in Main Menu each sending different values to Game.
So how can i set this value in other scenes script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to pass settings between the main menu scene and the game scene.

What you can do is create a `GameSettings` script that contains all your settings, and stick it on a game object of your main menu scene.
Store your settings in this script.

Loading the game scene would normally destroys all existing game objects, but Unity provides the `Object.DontDestroyOnLoad()` function that will prevent an object from being destroyed at loading.
Use this on your `GameSettings` script and it will exist in both the main menu and game scene and you will be able to retrieve your stored settings from the game scene.

Check the documentation for more info: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Here is an example:

```
public class GameSettings : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int NumberOfPlayer;
    /* Add other game settings here ... */

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Any variable declared `static` in a script will be preserved across scene changes. If you have a script in both scenes, and set the value of a static variable in one of the scenes, the script instance in the other scene will access the same value.

Comment: This is a good answer. But I think he is going to have a hard time using Statics. I think he needs a simpler one. He may come into method trying to access non static member, where new coders might get crazy. But yes, Static Variables is good. Just make sure you know the rules. Like Static Variables is Shared to other Classes, one change and all follows.